# JavaScript/jQuery - Get value of span of current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have some `<select>` elements and each of its possible options have a price inside span. I loop through all select tags and I need to get the value of the span of the selected option for each of them. So this is my code

```
 <select class="form-control config-option" id="s{{ $availableCategory->index}}">
   <option>{{ $availableCategory->default_option }}</option>
     @foreach($availableOptions as $availableOption)
           @if($availableOption->category->name == $availableCategory->name)
                 <option>({{ $availableOption->code }}) {{ $availableOption->name }} <span class="option-price">({{ $currency == 'EUR' ? 'EUR' : 'USD'}} {{ $availableOption->price }})</span></option>
           @endif
     @endforeach
 </select>
```

I tried to access it via the `find()` function of jQuery by class and by tag name but I fail to do so.

```
$('.config-option').each(function() {
     var currentElement = $(this);
     var optionPrice = currentElement.find('.option-price');
     console.log(optionPrice);
 });
```

If I console log `optionPrice.val()` I get undefined. So how can I access this span? Is there a better way to do it? A solution using plain JavaScript would do as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of Span Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343838/get-value-of-span-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't place tags inside option tag, that said try this

```
$('.config-option').each(function() { 
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var optionPrice = currentElement.find('.option-price').parent().text(); 
    console.log(optionPrice); 
});
```

updated: span tags get removed by browser so use this markup structure

```
<select>
    <option data-price="PRICE_HERE">
```

then use this in js

```
$('.config-option option:selected').each(function() { 
    var optionPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
    console.log(optionPrice); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that they get removed when I inspected in my browser.

Comment: you can give the option a class. see updated answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this produce the same result just like currentElement.val(); ?

Comment: That would give you the selected option only.

Comment: I just tested it and it works exactly the way I wanted! I totally forgot I could add a custom attribute to my option tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

spans don't have a value attribute (only inputs have that) so you need to get the .text() from the span

```
       $('.config-option').each(function() {
        var currentElement = $(this);
        var optionPrice = currentElement.find('.option-price').text();
        console.log(optionPrice);
    });
```

but why don't you just loop through and pick up the .option-price's specifically?

```
   $('.option-price').each(function() {
    var optionPrice = $(this).text();
    console.log(optionPrice);
});
```

Comment: I just tried it and I get an empty string even though it has a price inside it.

Answer (score 0):

`optionPrice.val()` is for `input` fields.

You need to call `optionPrice.text()` instead of this.

Try this

```
console.log(optionPrice.text());
```

Comment: may be your `span` don't have any data.

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(optionPrice);`?

Comment: I noticed that It is empty because when I inspected the span tag in the option tag vanishes.

Comment: then I think your condition, `@if($availableOption->category->name == $availableCategory->name)` will never satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add value to option of select box, then you will be easily get the value as

```
<select class="form-control config-option" id="s{{ $availableCategory->index}}">
    <option>{{ $availableCategory->default_option }}</option>
    @foreach($availableOptions as $availableOption)
        @if($availableOption->category->name == $availableCategory->name)
            <option value="({{ $currency == 'EUR' ? 'EUR' : 'USD'}} {{ $availableOption->price }})">({{ $availableOption->code }}) {{ $availableOption->name }} <span class="option-price">({{ $currency == 'EUR' ? 'EUR' : 'USD'}} {{ $availableOption->price }})</span></option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Script

```
$('.config-option').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);
    // Now you will be able to use val() function
    var optionPrice = currentElement.find('.option-price').val();
    console.log(optionPrice);
});
```