# How to get a span's text that contains "&nbsp" using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium ChromeDriver. I have a problem obtaining the contents of a `span` as defined in the screen shot below:

[image: Span I Am Trying To Work With]

I tried:

```
var text = element.Text;
```

but it returns an empty string.

The span's text is: "Yes, we can both go."

How can I get the span's text?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to reflect updates in the comments**

Because it's a span, which behaves much like a div element, there's no inherent text or value attribute at play--it's a container, and you'll need to grab the value from inside the span container (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343838/get-value-of-span-text) and this [article](http://xahlee.info/js/js_textContent_innerHTML_innerText_nodeValue.html)). Based on the fact you want the actual string value and not the html, the "textContent" attribute is probably the best bet.

You can use Selenium's "GetAttribute" method to get the "textContent" attribute of the span:

```
var textValue = element.GetAttribute("textContent");

// do code against textValue
```

There's no direct get accessor built into the Element class for attributes, so you'll need to pass in the string value for the name of the attribute you want, and it'll return the value if it's present.

Comment: Thank for your help. But return same result jdmac020

Comment: Hi jdmac020, I tried: element.Text; element.GetAttribute("innerText"); element.GetAttribute("text"); element.GetAttribute("value"); But not work for this element.
<span class="choice7 group1 drag no7 yui3-dd-draggable unplaced" style="width: 376px; height: 29px; line-height: 29px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; left: 461.156px; top: 770px;" id="yui_3_15_0_3_1546192163484_384">Yes,&nbsp;we&nbsp;can&nbsp;both&nbsp;go.</span>

Comment: @alienman alternately, maybe the "textContent" attribute is a better fit?

Comment: Thank you very much, jdmac020. "textContent" solved my problem.

Comment: @alienman fantastic! Glad to help. I updated the answer to reflect this, including a couple links as to how I found the solution. Feel free to accept the answer so the solution is clear to anyone coming after us.